# problema al redimensionar imágenes: se giran

Tags: php, html

Tengo un código para subir imágenes al servidor con PHP y ademas de subirlas las comprime para que no pesen tanto, pero tengo un problema sería el siguiente:

Algunas imágenes verticales las gira y las sube horizontales y no se como quitar eso del código.. necesito que suba la imagen y la comprima en tamaño igual como la estoy subiendo y no la rote a ningún lado.

El código esta bueno solo falta eso que no rote las imágenes subidas de vertical a horizontal

```html
<?php
//Tamaño y Formatos permitidos
$id = subida1;
if(isset($_FILES['images'])){
 
//Funciones optimizar imagenes
 
 
 
//Ruta de la carpeta donde se guardarán las imagenes
$patch='.';
 
 
//Parámetros optimización, resolución máxima permitida
$max_ancho = 1280;
$max_alto = 900;
 
 
if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'){
     
 
$medidasimagen= getimagesize($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);
 
//Si las imagenes tienen una resolución y un peso aceptable se suben tal cual
    if($medidasimagen[0] < 1280 && $_FILES['images']['size'] < 100000){
 
    $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['images']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $patch.'/'.$nombreArchivo);
     
}
 
 
//Si no, se generan nuevas imágenes optimizadas
else {
 
$nombreArchivo=$_FILES['images']['name'];
 
//Redimensionar
$rtOriginal=$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
 
if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg'){
$original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rtOriginal);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png'){
$original = imagecreatefrompng($rtOriginal);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'){
$original = imagecreatefromgif($rtOriginal);
}
 
  
list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($rtOriginal);
 
$x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
$y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;
 
 
if( ($ancho <= $max_ancho) && ($alto <= $max_alto) ){
    $ancho_final = $ancho;
    $alto_final = $alto;
}
elseif (($x_ratio * $alto) < $max_alto){
    $alto_final = ceil($x_ratio * $alto);
    $ancho_final = $max_ancho;
}
else{
    $ancho_final = ceil($y_ratio * $ancho);
    $alto_final = $max_alto;
}
 
$lienzo=imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final); 
 
imagecopyresampled($lienzo,$original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto);
  
//imagedestroy($original);
  
$cal=8;
 
if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg'){
imagejpeg($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombreArchivo);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png'){
imagepng($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombreArchivo);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'){
imagegif($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombreArchivo);
}
 
}
 
    }
    else echo 'fichero no soportado';
 
}
  
    header("Location: creartextos1.php?id=$id&nombreArchivo=$nombreArchivo");
   
   
?>
```

agradezco su ayuda muchísimas gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Cabe destacar que solo gira algunas imagenes y no todas

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal la lógica.

[image: Ejemplo de lógica]

Solo debes usar un valor de ratio para establecer el tamaño, dado que la imagen se debe escalar bajo un mismo porcentaje *(un solo valor de ratio ya sea reducir desde el alto o reducir desde ancho )*. Puedes identificar primero tu lado mas largo, si este supera el máximo correspondiente, aplicas el ratio sobre ese lado.

Solución seria usar un solo valor como el máximo tamaño de alto y ancho, después hallar un solo valor de ratio.

```html
<?php
//Tamaño y Formatos permitidos
$id = subida1;
if(isset($_FILES['images'])){
 
//Funciones optimizar imagenes
 
 
 
//Ruta de la carpeta donde se guardarán las imagenes
$patch='.';
 
 
//Parámetros optimización, resolución máxima permitida
$max_ancho = 1280;
$max_alto = 900;
$lado_mas_largo = 900;
 
 
if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'){
     
 
$medidasimagen= getimagesize($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);
 
//Si las imagenes tienen una resolución y un peso aceptable se suben tal cual
    if($medidasimagen[0] < 1280 && $_FILES['images']['size'] < 100000){
 
    $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['images']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $patch.'/'.$nombreArchivo);
     
}
 
 
//Si no, se generan nuevas imagenes optimizadas
else {
 
$nombreArchivo=$_FILES['images']['name'];
 
//Redimensionar
$rtOriginal=$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
 
if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg'){
$original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rtOriginal);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png'){
$original = imagecreatefrompng($rtOriginal);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'){
$original = imagecreatefromgif($rtOriginal);
}
 
  
list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($rtOriginal);
 
 
 
if( ($ancho <= $max_ancho) && ($alto <= $max_alto) ){
    $ancho_final = $ancho;
    $alto_final = $alto;
}else {
    // calculo el ratio según el lado más largo
   $lado_mas_largo = $ancho > $alto ? $ancho : $alto;
   $n_ratio = $max_ancho_alto / $lado_mas_largo;

   elseif (($n_ratio * $alto) < $max_alto){
      $alto_final = ceil($x_ratio * $alto);
      $ancho_final = $max_ancho_alto;
   }
   else{
      $ancho_final = ceil($n_ratio * $ancho);
      $alto_final = $max_ancho_alto ;
    }
}

 
$lienzo=imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final); 
 
imagecopyresampled($lienzo,$original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto);
  
//imagedestroy($original);
  
$cal=8;
 
if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg'){
imagejpeg($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombreArchivo);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png'){
imagepng($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombreArchivo);
}
else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'){
imagegif($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombreArchivo);
}
 
}
 
    }
    else echo 'fichero no soportado';
 
}
  
    header("Location: creartextos1.php?id=$id&nombreArchivo=$nombreArchivo");
   
   
?>
```

Comment: Hola amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero la verdad no se como aplicar lo que me estas diciendo la verdad es priemra vez que trato de hacer eso de ajustar el tamaño, me podrias ayudar? trate de cambiar algunos valores pero no he hecho que funcione

Comment: He corregido el código verifica , usando $max_ancho_alto como un único valor para el maximo tamaño.

Comment: Diego lo acabo de probar pero no sube la imagen al servidor, estoy tratando pero no logro dar con el fallo

Comment: Recordaste declarar el valor para la variable `$lado_mas_largo`

Comment: Lo probe pero aun nada amigo, no hay una forma de anular esa parte del codigo para que suba la imagen tal cual esta guardada, solo que la comprima?

Comment: hola amigo alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes hace un `loop` para reducir la imagen de tamaño es la solución menos elegante, pixel por pixel,  osea `while($ancho > $maxancho){  $ancho--;$alto--;  }`  y luego lo mismo con el alto  `while($alto > $maxalto){ $ancho--; $alto--; }` de esta manera se reduce el tamaño igual en ambos lados.
Tener en cuenta que el `$ancho--` reduce de a 1 pixel, pues entonces reducir digamos de a 20px primero y luego si la diferencia son 30px reducir de a 1.
`while ... { if ( $ancho+30 > $maxancho ) { $ancho--;$alto-- } else { $ancho-=20;$alto-=20; } ... }`